# How to link a new textview created on java with its xml characteristics in android studio?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

In Java, I have created a `TextView` whose text is the string written by the customer on an EditText in a previous activity. In the XML of the activity, I wrote the characteristics I want this `TextView` to have. My code creates a new `TextView` without those characteristics, anyone knows how to link them? I attach the java and XML codes. [javacode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTVp8.png) [xmlcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvXeW.png)Thanks in advance!

Comment: Avoid taking screenshots or your code..post your code snippet in your question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the textview properly.
In oncreate method add

```
TextView text_message_1;
text_message_1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_message_01);
```

Then set the text you get from other activity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a TextView dynamically, so there is no need define a TextView tag in XML. You can simply set properties of that TextView in Java and add it to any ViewGroup or Table or anything you want.

And you can also try using findViewById() method for that TextView.

If you still face any problem, let me know.
I hope it answers well.